# Where is the 'path' module required by app.js of an express application?

Tags: node.js, express

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
```

I'm just trying to understand Express more thoroughly. I can find all of the other modules, except `'path'`

Comment: To use Express, you do not need to require the `path` module yourself unless you're going to call specific path methods in your own code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`path` is a built-in node.js module. You can find it in [documentation](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/path.html).

Comment: thanks for the answer. Is it in a node_module directory somewhere else? Or where is that source code actually being pulled from when something in 'path' is called?

Comment: @CoreyStarbird it is installed with node.js and location are system dependent. On my system this modules located at `/usr/lib/nodejs`.